# WPF Browser Control when using ObjectForScripting window.external.invoke() throws object doesn't support property or method

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to capture click event from a WPF Browser Control webpage. I've created an ObjectForScriptingHelper class:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ObjectForScriptingHelper
{
    public void Invoke()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

And in the constructor of the WPF Window hosting the Web Browser control I'm using this helper class as the ObjectForScripting:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StandardWpfBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new ObjectForScriptingHelper();    
}
```

I then have a Uri variable `ViewPageUri` which I navigate to:

```
StandardWpfBrowser.Navigate(ViewPageUri);
```

Then in the page displayed by the browser control I have referenced jquery, added a button the html page and added javascript:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if (window.external === null)
        alert('ObjectForScripting is not set');
    else
    {
        alert('ObjectForScripting is set');
        window.external.Invoke();
    }
})
```

The `else` branch is being executed but error message `object doesn't support property or method 'Invoke'` is thrown.

All the tutorials and MSDN docs follow the approach above. Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW. `window.external` is browser built-in object and it is not `null`. the best way is call it directly with try-catch surrounded. do not check the method on external. it is not js object. it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else has this same issue. It turned out that naming the method `Invoke` was the problem. Once I changed the method name it all worked as expected.